# How to Randomly Choose Button Text in Java?

Tags: java, android, button, random

Friends,

I am a Civil Engineer. Now i am working now in Android Developing. I know Java and C# but i am mentally set my Programming knowledge is only editing like Reading and Understand. How to increase my skill like writing Programs Specially for C# and Java.

Thank You.

then its my Question..

For example I have 3 buttons and 3 int values.

How to make buttons text randomly choose from 3 int values string while button click.

It's a Simple maths game for Android Platforms.

```
        TextView textA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView textB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


        Random rand = new Random();
        final int x = rand.nextInt(1000);
        Random randB = new Random();
        int y = randB.nextInt(1000);
        Random randw = new Random();
        int w = randw.nextInt(1000);
        Random randz = new Random();
        int z = randz.nextInt(1000);

        int A = x;
        int B = y;
        int Wrong1 = (A + w);
        int Wrong2 = (A + z);
        final int CorrectAnswer = (A + B);

        String text = "text";
        Button[] arr = {button1, button2, button3};
        Random r = new Random();
        Button b = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
        b.setText(text);

        int Ans1 = CorrectAnswer;
        int Ans2 = Wrong1;
        int Ans3 = Wrong2;


        textA.setText("" + A);
        textB.setText("" + B);
        button1.setText("" + Wrong1);
        button2.setText("" + Wrong2);
        button3.setText("" + CorrectAnswer);
        final int ACAns;
        ACAns = Integer.parseInt(button3.getText().toString());
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int AAns = Integer.parseInt(button1.getText().toString());


                if ((AAns == ACAns)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int BAns = Integer.parseInt(button2.getText().toString());
                int ACAns = Integer.parseInt(button1.getText().toString());
                if ((BAns == ACAns)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    }    
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int CAns = Integer.parseInt(button3.getText().toString());
                int ACAns = Integer.parseInt(button3.getText().toString());
                if ((CAns == ACAns)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                      

                    return;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Store the values in an `array` and pick one on click

Comment: i need to set Button text randomly... how??

Comment: Sorry, could not understand what you actually want. Do you want to set button text from array randomly or generate text string randomly and set it as button text?

Comment: i need to set Wrong1, Wrong2, CorrectAnswer string to Button Text. Buttons are get this values in randomly like Button1.getText(wrong1 or Wrong2 or CorrectAnswer) if Button1 Choose Wrong1 then Button2 Choose Randomly from Wrong2 and CorrectAnswer..

Comment: I think I know what you want to do. Check my answer and comment if it's not what you want to do. But the best thing might be to rephrase a little bit your question as it quite unclear what you want to do in the first place. Hope my answer helps though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the string values in an array of size 3.
Generate a random number between 0 and 2. Keep that value in a variable and assign the string associated to that value to your button. Reduce your array by deleting the string you've already assigned. Then generate a random int between 0 and 1. Assign again to a button. Delete the element you've just assigned and finally assign the last string value to your last button.

Sorry for the lack of code but I'm on my phone, it's not really easy to code on phones.

Hope this helps

Comment: Friends, I am a Civil Engineer. Now i am working now in Android Developing. I know Java and C# but i am mentally set my Programming knowledge is only editing like Reading and Understand. How to increase my skill like writing Programs Specially for C# and Java. Thank You.

Comment: Such a question is not really subject for a comment or even a question on SO. I believe that google has plenty of answers to that question. Anyway, best way to learn programming is actually to program. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Take two arrays.

```
String buttonNamesArray[] = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
int indexArray[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

Now generate a random number by any logic and do a modulus by 3 (length of indexArray) operation to get an index in the range [0-2]. Now do

```
randomIndex = randomNumber % 3;
if(indexArray[randomIndex] != -1) {
    //assign the next button value buttonNamesArray[randomIndex]
    indexArray[randomIndex] = -1;
}
```

Perform this in a loop until all buttons are not over.

This is just the logic and not the actual code.

Comment: Friends,

I am a Civil Engineer. Now i am working now in Android Developing. I know Java and C# but i am mentally set my Programming knowledge is only editing like Reading and Understand. How to increase my skill like writing Programs Specially for C# and Java.

Thank You.

Comment: Performance is not an issue for that special case, but using an array and removing values every step is better I think. Besides, I might be wrong but I think you do not take into account the fact that the random generation could give you three times the same value

Comment: @LonniBesançon I agree on the fact that the loop can run multiple times. Exactly the reason why random number generation logic has not been discussed. Also the presumption in not deleting the strings was that for next random assignment the array will have to be reinitialized and this being a game the frequency will be more. To save the initialization and deletion overhead this approach was considered. For one time assignment I will go with the one you suggested.

Comment: You're completely right, I didn't think about it as something that would happen more that once actually. Upvote deserved ;)

Comment: @sabish You can try solving problems from sites like [CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/) or [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/). These problems will help you increase your basic problem solving ability. Which is the core to solving any problem. Hope this helps.

Such comments are not greatly accepted on SO though.